# Dictionary to Custom KeyValuePair list - can't convert (C# .Net 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I read that dictionary and KeyValuePair can not be written by the xml serializer.
So I wrote my own KeyValuePair struct.

```
public struct CustomKeyValuePair<Tkey, tValue>
{
   public Tkey Key { get; set; }
   public tValue Value { get; set; }

   public CustomKeyValuePair(Tkey key,tValue value) : this()
   {
      this.Key = key;
      this.Value = value; 
   }
}
```

But when I do this, I get an error, that it can't convert:

```
List<CustomKeyValuePair<string, AnimationPath>> convList = 
                   Templates.ToList<CustomKeyValuePair<string, AnimationPath>>();
```

It works on the normal keyValuePair, but not on my custom one. So whats the problem?
I tried to copy the original as close as possible, but it doesn't want to convert my dictionary (Templates) to that list. I can't see that it uses any interface or inherits from a struct to do that. Do I have to add all the entries manually?

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: What's the definition of Template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` implements both `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Tkey, Tvalue>>` and `ICollection<KeyValuePair<Tkey, Tvalue>>`:

(from metadata shown in Visual Studio):

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
     ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
     IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
```

That's why `ToList()` with `KeyValuePair` works and the other doesn't.

Your best bet is probably to use:

```
List<CustomKeyValuePair<string, AnimationPath>> convList = 
    Templates.Select(kv => new CustomKeyValuePair(kv.Key, kv.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that works :)
Didn't know that dictionary inherits from it.